# Will leaving a wet jacket to dry in a server room damage any equipment?

Tags: server-room

It rained on my way in to work this morning and I was absolutely deluged by the time I made it in. I took my jacket off and hung it over the handles of one of those trolley/wheelie things people use to move tall, heavy things (the ones with the short base, but that's not important) in the server room to dry. We have one floor-to-ceiling cabinet with about 10 servers running in it, and an AC unit battling to keep the temperature under 25'C.

Anyway, my boss is concerned that the evaporating moisture could cause damage to the server equipment. The jacket is placed so it can't drip on anything electronic, so is there any real cause for alarm?

Comment: How big is the room?

Comment: Why are you asking the internet? Move the jacket.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's generally not considered appropriate to bring anything liquid, or wet into a server room/datacenter. There is a balance of moisture that should be in the air, just make sure moisture is not condensing.

The first time I saw coffee spilled into the Domino server, I have been overly strict on liquids in my server rooms... just as a rule-of-thumb.